# Optimal way to make multiple independent requests to server in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-http

I want to make to multiple requests to same server in an optimal way. So I have

```
Future<List<Item>> getAllItems() async {
    var client = new http.Client();
    List<String> itemsIds = ['1', '2', '3']; //different ids
    List<Item> itemList = [];
    for (var item in itemsIds) {
      //make call to server eg: 'sampleapi/1/next' etc
      await client.get('sampleapi/' + item + '/next').then((response) {
        //Do some processing and add to itemList

      });
    }
    client.close();
    return itemList;
}
```

Now, the api calls are made one after other. But the api calls are independent of each other. Whats the best way to implement so as to avoid the async await hell?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `Future.wait(...)` to wait for a set of `Future`s to complete:

```
Future<List<Item>> getAllItems() async {
    var client = new http.Client();
    List<String> itemsIds = ['1', '2', '3']; //different ids

    return Future.wait<Item>(['1', '2', '3'].map((item) =>
      client.get('sampleapi/' + item + '/next').then((response) {
        //Do some processing and add to itemList
        return foo; // some Item that is the result of this request 
      });
    );
}
```

See also https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-async/Future/wait.html

Comment: i am making multiple calls to same server using different future methods but it returns me empty body id i make single http call it works fine

Comment: Not sure. Perhaps you expect one requests to be made only after the previous one completed. They are made concurrently. If one request depends on another one to be completed previously, this won't work. If this is not the case in your situation, I don't know what causes it.

Comment: let me try the  above solution hope it will work for and thanks for the reply

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can store these 3 APIs data on local 3 tables DB using SQLite?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "this 3 APIs`, but sure, why not?

Answer (score 15):

Günter beat me to it by a couple minutes, but I've already typed it out so here's a slight alternative which would also work and avoids using 'then' completely.

```
Future<List<Item>> getAllItems() async {
  var client = new Client();
  List<String> itemsIds = ['1', '2', '3']; //different ids

  List<Response> list = await Future.wait(itemsIds.map((itemId) => client.get('sampleapi/$itemId/next')));

  return list.map((response){
    // do processing here and return items
    return new Item();
  }).toList();
}
```

Comment: can store these 3 APIs data on local 3 tables DB using SQLite?