# Dart - How to multiple http.post request with different bodies

Tags: dart, flutter

I found this: [Optimal way to make multiple independent requests to server in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027632/optimal-way-to-make-multiple-independent-requests-to-server-in-dart)

But my issue is a bit different.

I want to make multiple posts with different bodies but I get the same results, which is related to the last element of types list.

```
final List<String> types = ['completed', 'approval', 'process', 'available'];
```

Think about this list, I'm always getting 'completed' type results.

```
Future<List<dynamic>> fetchAllRequests() async {
  int i = 0;
  userInfo['type'] = types.first;
  return Future.wait(
    types.map(
      (t) => client.post(Api.requests, body: userInfo).then(
            (response) {
              if (i < types.length - 1) {
                userInfo['type'] = types[++i];
              }
              Map<String, dynamic> m = jsonDecode(response.body);
              dataItemsLists.add(m['DataItems']);
              print('${m['DataItems']}');
            },
          ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Also, I want to manipulate the body inside the map() fun, but this is not working:

```
types.map((t){client.post)(Api.requests, body: userInfo).then()...}
```

Error log:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'then' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: then<dynamic>(Closure: (dynamic) => Null, onError: 
Closure: (dynamic, StackTrace) => Null)
```

While this is working:

```
types.map((t) => client.post)(Api.requests, body: userInfo).then()...
```

So I manipulate in a verbose mode the body as you see in my first code block up above instead of like this way:

```
Future<List<dynamic>> fetchAllRequests() async {
  return Future.wait(
    types.map((String t) {
      userInfo['type'] = t;
      client.post(Api.requests, body: userInfo).then(
        (response) {
          Map<String, dynamic> m = jsonDecode(response.body);
          dataItemsLists.add(m['DataItems']);
          print('${m['DataItems']}');
        },
      );
    }),
  );
}
```

Comment: What is `types.map((t){client.post)(Api.requests, body: userInfo).then()...}` supposed to do? What is the closing `)` after `client.post` for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `{}` instead of `=>`, then you need to explicitly `return`

Here the result of `.map(...)` is `null` because nothing is returned

```
types.map((t){client.post)(Api.requests, body: userInfo).then()...}
```

Either use

```
types.map((t) => client.post)(Api.requests, body: userInfo).then()...;
```

or

```
types.map((t){return client.post)(Api.requests, body: userInfo).then()...}
```

Similar in your last code block

```
  client.post(Api.requests, body: userInfo).then(
```

should be

```
  return client.post(Api.requests, body: userInfo).then(
```

Comment: omg, this is ridiculous, shame on me :), seriously I need more sleeping :)
It's all about return. Now it's working. Sorry for the inconvenience Gunter, really :)

Comment: :D Sleep tight .